# Great Expectations - expect_column_pair_values_to_not_be_equal

Tags: great-expectations, expectations

Is there a way to achieve the expectation: `expect_column_pair_values_to_not_be_equal` without having to create a custom expectation. If not what is the easiest way to create a custom expectation doing the desired outcome which is basically a alternative to the already existing `expect_column_pair_values_to_be_equal` function.

I have tried to search the internet for an answer if there is a way to achieve the desired outcome, however I did not find anything. The only viable solution ChatGPT provided was to create a custom expectation, but I am not an expert in that area and I would want to avoid it if possible, as I do not fully understand how that works.

Comment: Hey not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this. Been recently working on this library https://github.com/SuperiorityComplex/data_checks/tree/main for writing and deploying more lightweight data checks. You can use it alongside GE but can also write any other Python data check with scheduling and alerting built in